# handling of timestamps in networkx

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp, networkx

When trying to write a `GEXF` file from networkx:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

data  = pd.DataFrame({'src':[1,2], 'dst':[2,1], 'attr_1':['foo', 'bar'], 'time':[pd.Timestamp.now(), pd.Timestamp.now()]})
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(data, source='src',
                            target='dst',
                           edge_attr=['attr_1', 'time'],
                           create_using= nx.MultiGraph())
nx.write_gexf(G, "visualization.gexf")
```

An error of:

```
attribute value type is not allowed: <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
```

can be observed.
Is there no other way than string formatting the timestamp for networkx to handle it?

Comment: `NetworkX` is ok with timestamps. It's `GexF` schema that doesn't like timestamps